# Fetching data before rendering server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-router, isomorphism

Right now I'm discovering **Este.js** and I have a little issue with isomorphic apps. I don't understand how to make api call before rendering server side with renderToString().

One solution consists in doing all the data fetching at the router level using React Router. Depending on the top level route, I can predict which data will be needed, make the api call, and then call React.renderToString.

Great, but I still have to declare the data dependencies at the component level AND in the router level. I end up writing the same code twice, and I don't believe it's the best way to do it.

EDIT : Ok, for now I'm able to do somewhat what I want. Using React-Router and this [link](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run) I've been able to made the following :

Giving this global app state, I want to prefetch todos when pointing /todos

### initialstate.js

```
{
  auth: {
    data: null,
    form: null
  },
  examples: {
    editable: {
      state: null,
      text: 'Some inline-editable text.'
    }
  },
  i18n: {
    formats: {},
    locales: initialLocale,
    messages: messages[initialLocale]
  },
  pendingActions: {},
  todos: {
    editables: {},
    newTodo: {
      title: ''
    },
    list: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'first todo yipiyo'
    }]
  },
  users: {
    viewer: null
  }
}
```

### todos.react.js

In todo component I declare a static function fetchData. Because I want to retrieve the correct key in my appState, I pass 'list' as a param. Feels dirty.

```
class Todos extends Component {

  static fetchData(){
    return actions.loadAllTodos('list');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Todos.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }

}
```

### actions.js

Api call and stuff, I pass the key to the promise - Feels hacky

```
export function loadAllTodos(key) {

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    Api.get()
    .then(res => {
      res.key = key; //hacky time
      resolve(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    })

  });

  return dispatch(loadAllTodos, promise);

}
```

### render.js

```
router.run((Handler, routerState) => {

  var promise = Promise.all(routerState.routes
        .filter(route => route.handler.fetchData)
        .map(route => {
          return route.handler.fetchData();
        })
      );

  promise.then(resp => {

    console.log(resp);

    //Displays : 
    [ { id: 2, title: 'Im a second todo' },{ id: 3, title: 'I like todo' },
    cursor: 'list' ]

    //Some stuff to add resp to appState, using the correct key, yey iso+api=win
    appState = mergeThisWithMagic(appState, resp);

    const html = preloadAppStateThenRenderHtml(Handler, appState);
    const notFound = routerState.routes.some(route => route.name ===
      'not-found');
    const status = notFound ? 404 : 200;
    res.status(status).send(html);
    resolve();

  });


});
```

As you can see, I'll create a function to update appState with the updated todoList.

Is this ok to do all of this ? I would like to have some feedback please, because I feel like I'm going in a dark path :(.

Comment: Relay will address this issue, until then I'm not sure if there is a library for this. I definitely think defining your data dependencies in the component is the way to go - you shouldn't need to repeat this at router level, at router level you need to collect the data dependencies from the components. I found this talk pretty helpful on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ebP9Bf1bk

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look ! I updated my question, feel free to tell me what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accomplished this in my isomorphic server side app by putting my fetchData functions in the `statics` object of the component(s) and using promises that wait until all the data is returned before rendering the app to string.

Then you would pass the returned data down to the rendered component via props. This example was instrumental in my development of this app. [React Router Mega Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo).

Comment: How did you deal with redundant calls to the API's? I use the same method but then I also use `componentDidMount` to load for client-side rendering. But those get fired unnecessarily after server-side rendering

Comment: Great question. First, you'll want to serialize the data that you just fetched on the server and pass it into the client somehow. I use EJS, but you could use any templating tool. Then, when you initiate your client side code, "seed" it with the data you just sent over. In order to prevent duplicate calls, I also implemented a "cache_once" prop on my API so that it would cache the results and use that instead of another API call. The React Router Mega Demo is a great example.