# Issue with loading dynamic meta tag value in react app using server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, meta-tags, server-side-rendering

I have the react application uses the server side rendering. I used [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) as for display dynamic meta tags. Everything is setups perfectly. Also the dynamic meta tags are being display to the browser correctly but at server side it takes values undefined. Is anyone tell me its solution what to do.

For example :

```
var React = require('react');
var Helmet = require('react-helmet');

var About = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      title: "",
      description: "",
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: api_url+'/get_meta',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function( response ) {
        if( response.status==200 ){
          this.setState({title: response.title, description: response.title });
        }
      }
    });  
  },
  render: function() {
    var title = this.state.title;
    var description = this.state.description;
    return (
        <div>
          <Helmet
            title={title}
            meta={[
              {"name": "description", "content": description }
            ]}
          />
          <p>
            This is the title page
          </p>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = About;
```

When I view the source it doesn't display anything in meta tag, but when I inspect the browser element it shows the meta tag value.
After debugging a while, I found the issue, the component is renders both server and client side, So at server side it is rendering the component with initial state only, that's why the value is not being display.

Please anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: You can't get actual `source` for any `react` app. Since it's `DOM` rendering library. In source we can get static `HTML` content in `.html` page, not the dynamic `DOM` rendered by `react`

Comment: Any alternate solution Please?

Comment: You shouldn't try to 'render the source' it will always be DOM rendered... You should figure out a way to populate the data before it is rendered by React.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Are you agree with  Richardsondx reply?

Comment: Where do you want to use that `meta` actually?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja On the specific page, when I view the page source meta-tag should appear.

Comment: Your `DOM` specified `Meta` may not be visible in `page-source` unless you write explicitly in `.html` file

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja, It works when I wrote like this,
<Helmet
            title="About static title"
            meta={[
              {"name": "description", "content": "About static description" }
            ]}
          />
Having the issue with assigning dynamic values.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is not called on the server, only on the client. You'd need to move your $.ajax call to `componentWillMount` since that is called on the server (and the client...). However, it's asynchronous and also might not work to prefetch data - you might need to use react-router or you can check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974007/fetching-data-before-rendering-server-side